# Change The Size Of A Custom UI CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm attempting to use "MaterialSkin" for a c# program. I want to resize it, however it has auto resizing as true. If I disable it, the size of the actual box does not change. The default size is far too big. [auto resizing enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek0zb.png)[auto size off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0szk0.png)
i would really like to use this but I don't know how to fix this issue.

tried disabling auto size

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.